# Runing php on server side issue

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

Please forgive the simplicity of this question. The answer will be obvious to many of you. But since I'm completely new to php and JSON, and I can't find a concrete answer on Google, I need to ask.

I have the following:

- Client side Android app
- mySQL database on server
- JSON in between

The question is very simple. Where on the server do I put the php file? Any directory? A specific location? I just need a simple working answer. Not concerned about security or anything fancy at this stage. Please help.

Also, does anyone know of a very simple tutorial that talks about php, json, and working on the server side for someone like me who's completely new to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server must be available with a one of the given folders

1. public_html
2. www
3. htdocs

if any of the folder you can see in your server then this is the place where you need to place your php files

basic Introductory Tutorial for PHP with examples

[tizag.com](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/)

Basic Introductory Tutorial For JSON

[JSON](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorials/json/)

[JSON with PHP](http://www.itnewb.com/tutorial/Introduction-to-JSON-and-PHP)

Answer (score 1):

As long as the php file is accessible by http you are fine.  So pretty much anywhere.

here is a tutorial.  http://www.itnewb.com/tutorial/Introduction-to-JSON-and-PHP

Answer (score 1):

To run your php script you will need an http server on your server that handles php script.

For example you can use the apache web server with mod_php. You then can put your php file in the server default web folder or configure another one.

Comment: What is the name of this default folder? Where would it be? Is it called "web folder"?

Comment: It depends of your system, i only use debian linux system so what i can tell is that the default is /var/www. But you can find it by reading the documentation for your system or read the http server configuration page. For an apache server, the configurations files are mostly found in /etc/apache2. You can also tell your web server to use another folder or even create different folders for different websites. For more complex tunning you can create aliases (which mean assigning location: eg domain.com/webapp is located in /home/name/myawebapp). Or you can create virutal hosts.